# Advent of Code 2018 Day 4 - Pythonic Sleepy Guards

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge

#### Introduction

I'm using Advent of Code 2018 to learn Python better, interested in the new type support for Python 3.7, I decided to go with that.

Here is my solution to [Advent of Code Day 4](https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/4), both part 1 and 2. I'm returning the answers for both part 1 and 2 as a tuple.

#### Problem Description

The problem essentially boils down to: Given a timestamped unsorted list of events of guards beginning their shift, waking up and falling asleep, determine the following:

Part 1: Which guard is asleep the most and on which minute is that guard mostly asleep? Return guard id multiplied by the minute number.

Part 2: Which guard is most frequently asleep on the same minute? Again, return guard id multiplied by the minute number.

For full problem description, please see [Advent of Code Day 4](https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/4)

#### Concerns

I'm a big fan of Java 8 Stream API and C# Linq, I kind of expected Python to be more like that. I'm not sure if the nested function calls like `sorted(list(...))` or `len(list(...))` are *"Pythonic"*. Likewise, it feels like I should be able to use some reducer-like function calls instead of imperatively looping through stuff to find the most common sleeper of some kind. Or is the way I have written this code the Python way to do it?

#### Code

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import datetime
from days import read_file
from enum import Enum
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple
from statistics import mode
import statistics
import operator
import re


class EventType(Enum):
    STARTS_SHIFT = 1
    FALLS_ASLEEP = 2
    WAKES_UP = 3


@dataclass
class Event:
    time: datetime
    guard: int
    event: EventType


@dataclass
class GuardSleep:
    sleep_total: int
    last_sleep: int
    sleeps: list

    def add_sleeps(self, minute):
        for i in range(self.last_sleep, minute):
            self.sleeps.append(i)


def get_guard(line: str):
    if "Guard" in line:
        guard_id = re.search("Guard #(\\d+)", line)
        return int(guard_id.group(1))
    return -1


def event_type(line):
    if "begins shift" in line:
        return EventType.STARTS_SHIFT
    if "falls asleep" in line:
        return EventType.FALLS_ASLEEP
    if "wakes up" in line:
        return EventType.WAKES_UP
    raise Exception("Unknown line: " + line)


def day4() -> (int, int):
    events = sorted(list(Event(datetime.strptime(line[1:17], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), get_guard(line), event_type(line)) for line in read_file(4)), key=operator.attrgetter("time"))

    guard = -1
    guardsleep = defaultdict(lambda: GuardSleep(0, 0, []))
    for event in events:
        if event.guard >= 0:
            guard = event.guard

        if event.event == EventType.FALLS_ASLEEP:
            guardsleep[guard].last_sleep = event.time.minute

        if event.event == EventType.WAKES_UP:
            guardsleep[guard].sleep_total += event.time.minute - guardsleep[guard].last_sleep
            guardsleep[guard].add_sleeps(event.time.minute)

    most_sleepy_guard_number = max(guardsleep, key=(lambda key: guardsleep[key].sleep_total))

    most_sleepy_guard = guardsleep[most_sleepy_guard_number]
    part1_result = most_sleepy_guard_number * mode(sorted(most_sleepy_guard.sleeps))

    # Part 2
    MostSleepy = namedtuple('MostCommon', ['id', 'minute', 'amount'])
    most_sleepy = MostSleepy(0, 0, 0)
    for k in guardsleep:
        current_guard = guardsleep[k]
        try:
            most_common_minute = mode(sorted(current_guard.sleeps))
            amount = len(list((m for m in current_guard.sleeps if m == most_common_minute)))
            if amount > most_sleepy.amount:
                most_sleepy = MostSleepy(k, most_common_minute, amount)
        except statistics.StatisticsError:
            print("No unique most common minute for " + str(k))

    return part1_result, most_sleepy.id * most_sleepy.minute


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(day4())
```

Answer (score 5):

### Replacing chained `if` with dictionary lookup

This function:

```
def event_type(line):
    if "begins shift" in line:
        return EventType.STARTS_SHIFT
    if "falls asleep" in line:
        return EventType.FALLS_ASLEEP
    if "wakes up" in line:
        return EventType.WAKES_UP
    raise Exception("Unknown line: " + line)
```

isn't bad, but chained `if` like this smell. It may be better represented as a dictionary, where the key is the string above, the value is the enum value, and you do a simple key lookup based on the last two words of every line. Whereas chained `if` is worst-case O(n), dictionary lookup is O(1). Then - no `if`s needed, and you get the exception for free if key lookup fails.

### Use raw strings

```
re.search("Guard #(\\d+)", line)
```

should be

```
re.search(r"Guard #(\d+)", line)
```

### Settle down with the one-liners

This:

```
events = sorted(list(Event(datetime.strptime(line[1:17], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), get_guard(line), event_type(line)) for line in read_file(4)), key=operator.attrgetter("time"))
```

is effectively illegible. Break this up into multiple lines - including a temporary variable for the `strptime`, as well as linebreaks in the list comprehension itself.

### Don't use lists if you can use tuples

This:

```
MostSleepy = namedtuple('MostCommon', ['id', 'minute', 'amount'])
```

should be

```
MostSleepy = namedtuple('MostCommon', ('id', 'minute', 'amount'))
```

for various reasons - tuples are immutable, so use them for immutable data; and under certain narrow contexts (certainly not this one) they're faster.

### Use a sum instead of a list constructor

This:

```
amount = len(list((m for m in current_guard.sleeps if m == most_common_minute)))
```

should be

```
amount = sum(1 for m in current_guard.sleeps if m == most_common_minute)
```

(Also, even if you kept using `len`, you should use a `tuple` constructor instead of a `list` constructor.)

Another footnote - don't put inner parens in expressions like `list((...generator...))`. Constructors can accept generator expressions directly.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your logic on the tuple vs list in the call to `namedtuple`.  The second argument (field names) can be a list, tuple, string, etc.  I think it's largely irrelevant which you choose.

Also while technically I suppose it's true that worst-case chained if's is O(n), so is dictionary lookup if you have lots of collisions.  I agree that in some instances dictionary lookup can stand-in for if branches, but I think that is somewhat a preference or dictated by the number of branches you have (e.g. 100 diff conditionals would be a sign of a problem).

Comment: I would however suggest that he use "elif" instead of multiple "if" statements.  In this scenario, the "if" statements are mutually exclusive, so it doesn't make a difference, but the conveyed intent could be misleading in other circumstances.  If you want only one branch to execute, as opposed to each time there is a match, use "elif".

Answer (score 3):

You could eliminate some of the many dependencies:

- Since you're already using `@dataclass`, you could use it for `MostSleepy` instead of `namedtuple`
- It looks strange to `import statistics` after `from statistics import mode`. Aside from `mode`, the only other thing used from it is `StatisticsError`. So you could use `from statistics import mode, StatisticsError` and not import the entire `statistics`
- I don't see the `enum` doing anything useful. You could remove it and the program will still work.
- The `operator` is not very useful either. You could replace `operator.attrgetter("time")` with `lambda t: t.time`

The `add_sleeps` function could be written more compactly:

```
def add_sleeps(self, minute):
    self.sleeps.extend(list(range(self.last_sleep, minute)))
```

When creating the `events` list,
you used helper functions `get_guard` and `event_type`.
It would have been good to do the same for the time too.

The `last_sleep` attribute doesn't belong in `GuardSleep`.
It's an implementation detail of the parsing of the lines,
it has no other use for a `GuardSleep` instance.

Instead of string concatenation like `"foo " + str(bar)`,
the recommended way is f-strings, `f"foo {bar}"`.

The input would have allowed some simplifications.
For example, alphabetic sorting of the lines gives the same results as sorting by time.
And, it seems all the "falls asleep" and "wakes up" events happen in the 0th hour.
As such, you could just parse the minute instead of the entire time:

```
events = [Event(int(line[15:17]), get_guard(line), event_type(line)) for line in sorted(read_file(4))]
```